# C# Regex.replace Pattern needed

Tags: c#, regex, replace

Usually I make my `Regex` patterns by myself, but I can't figure this one out:
I need a `Regex.Replace` that replaces "'Number'/'Number'" to "'Number'von'Number'".

Example: "2/5" schould become "2von5".

The problem is that I can't just replace "/" to "von" because there are other "/" that are needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can replace `(?<=\d)/(?=\d)` with `von`, using [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Another option is to replace `(\d)/(\d)` with `$1von$2` (though that would fail on `1/2/3`).